# Need help in laravel forms / retrieve inputs with translation while validating

Tags: laravel, validation, caching

I have Laravel 7 form with many inputs, need to retrieve the inputs while validating,
this in the form blade

````
```
    <input type="text" value="{!! clean($translation->title) !!}" placeholder="{{__("Title")}}" name="title" class="form-control"> 
```
````

need to know how to use old in such case to retrieve the inputs.

Thanks

Comment: Does `value="{{ old('title') }}"` not work?

Comment: @Unflux:   its working, but is it correct as a chang for `value="{!! clean($translation->title) !!}"` ? or will be a problem with the translation later?  Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but you can do `value="{{ old('title', clean($translation->title)) }}"`.

Comment: I have the form in 3 languages and using this

Comment: @Unflux the form is multi-languages and the code includes this `<input type="text" value="{!! clean($translation->title) !!}" placeholder="{{__("Title")}}" name="title" class="form-control">` for the translation inputs.

Comment: Yes and the first parameter of `old` will return whatever the user inputs if validation fails whilst the second parameter will return the value of `$translation->title` if it exists. So if the user inputs French and validation fails, they will get French back.

Comment: @Unflux thanks for your help, the title is working, but  th rest is not returning the inputs with this    `<textarea name="content" class="d-none has-ckeditor" cols="30" rows="10">{{old('content'),$translation->content}}</textarea>`

Comment: You need to have the translation as the second parameter for `old`. `{{ old('content', $translation->content) }}`

Comment: @Unflux  Thanks very much! will try to change all inputs and check!